# What are steps for application gateway disaster recovery?

Tags: azure-application-gateway

We are finalizing a BCP/DR plan for accreditation and want to capture steps for application gateway disaster recovery. We want to provide proof that the steps we detailed in the plan are reproducible and feasible in times of Disaster recovery. We first want to try this out in a nonproduction setting.

Would this steps be ideal for a DR scenario for an application gateway?

1. Export existing gateway template (production, since thats the only one we have)
2. Recreate the gateway on test/staging (may have to edit some of the configs in the exported template)
3. Create a test DNS and point to the public IP of the new Application Gateway.
4. connect an App service under this test gateway

or is it better for us to Use Traffic Manager to distribute traffic across multiple application gateways in different datacenters?

[image: appgateway]

Answer (score 0):

Using Traffic Manager to distribute traffic across multiple application gateways in different datacenters is the best approach to achieve this DR scenario.

Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#how-do-i-achieve-a-dr-scenario-across-datacenters-by-using-application-gateway

Disaster recovery using Traffic Manager provides several approaches to achieve failover and high availability via redundant architecture. Some of the popular approaches are mentioned in the below doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/networking/disaster-recovery-dns-traffic-manager

Architecture, components & considerations for this type of setup can be found in the below doc:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/high-availability/reference-architecture-traffic-manager-application-gateway